# Find value if 3 continuance data available in one row of EXCEL

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have data like below:

[image]

I need to find first date if 3 continuance none zero data available.

Out put should be like below:

[image]

I can find first place that none zero data available but not know how to check 3 continuance day have data 
here is my code for finding first cell address with none zero data:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(C2:H2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C2:H2>0,0),)))
```

and the result is like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `I2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:F$1,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:F2>0)*(C2:G2>0)*(D2:H2>0),),0)),"")
```

Drag down.